# How can I load only the appropriate video in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have two videos, one for mobile and one for desktop. I use a media query to display them. My question is: Do both still "load"? I use a very small file for the mobile version but it seems to take forever to load still, which leads me to believe both are still being loaded. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<video class="headVid1" playsinline autoplay muted loop preload="auto" id="bgvid">
    <source src="resources/css/img/backvidDesk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>       
<video class="headVid2" playsinline autoplay muted loop preload="auto" id="bgvid">
    <source src="resources/css/img/backvidMob3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
.headVid2{
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
    .headVid1{
        display: none;
    }
    .headVid2{
        display: block;
    }
    video#bgvid{
        max-width:100vw !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, they both load and also play in theory (unless a browser added a functionality to prevent it that i don't know). The whole video tag could be added conditionnally by javascript on page load for example

Answer (score 0):

You should set appropriate preload attribute ("none"). Example:

```
<video class="headVid1" playsinline autoplay muted loop preload="none" id="bgvid">
    <source src="resources/css/img/backvidDesk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>       
<video class="headVid2" playsinline autoplay muted loop preload="none" id="bgvid">
    <source src="resources/css/img/backvidMob3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<video _ngcontent-bvp-c9="" id="vid_html5_api" playsinline="playsinline" preload="auto" class="vjs-tech" tabindex="-1" role="application" src="blob:https://www.israelhayom.co.il/6ecb1326-1468-4a15-9032-3fa5a2996e59"> &lt;source type="application/x-mpegURL" src=&gt; <track kind="metadata" label="segment-metadata"></video>
```